# Multiple broadcasting in a loop using LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent) from a service don't update the activity UI after each call

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a service which communicates with the activity using LocalBroadcastManager every time it gets a location update.
The callback in the service is:

```
  @Synchronized private fun requestLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    createLocationRequest()
    val locationCallback: LocationCallback?
    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            synchronized(this) {
                    while (...) {
        
        sendBroadcast(speed, volume)
        sleep(500)
    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        mLocationRequest,
        locationCallback,
        Looper.getMainLooper()
    )
}

    private fun sendBroadcast(speed: Double, volume : Int) {
    val intent = Intent(BROADCAST_INTENT)
    intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_SPEED, speed)
    intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_VOLUME, volume)
    mBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

The activity has an onrecieve handler:

```
    private val broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        handleIntent(intent)
    }
}

private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
    if (intent.action == BROADCAST_INTENT) {
        val speed = intent.getDoubleExtra(BROADCAST_SPEED, 0.0)
        mTextViewSpeed.text = speed
        val volume = intent.getIntExtra(BROADCAST_VOLUME, 0)
        mTextViewVolume.text = volume
    }
}
```

When debugging with a breakpoint where the TextView is supposed to get updated, I see the calls to update the views run multiple times with different values. But the UI only updates with the last value.

Why is it not updated immediately? Any way to fix it?

Comment: Is the `while ...` loop running in the `Service` on the main (UI) Thread?

Comment: In the service.

Comment: Being called from what method in the `Service`? Looks like this isn't running in a background/worker Thread. You need to make sure that that method is running in a background/worker Thread and not on the main (UI) Thread.

Comment: It's called from a locationcallback which runs everytime a location is updated it uses the fusedlocation class. I updated the question with the whole callback.

Comment: OK, The location callback runs on the main (UI) Thread. You need to ensure this runs on a background Thread. I'll attach an answer for you, just a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `while...` loop is running on the main (UI) Thread. This is not only causing your problem, but is also very very bad. No UI updates can happen while this `while...` loop is running, so your app will be very sluggish and Android may kill it off with an ANR (Application Not Responding) error.

To fix this, make sure that your location callback gets run on another Thread. Something like this:

In `onCreate()` of your `Service`, create and start a `HandlerThread`:

```
private val mHandlerThread = HandlerThread("locationUpdates")
mHandlerThread.start()
```

Now, pass the `Looper` of that `HandlerThread` to the fused location client:

```
mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
    mLocationRequest,
    locationCallback,
    mHandlerThread.getLooper()
)
```

This will ensure that the location callbacks get executed on the `HandlerThread` and not on the main (UI) Thread.

Make sure to stop the `HandlerThread` in `onDestroy()` of the `Service` like this:

```
mHandlerThread.quit()
```

Comment: You are awesome, it worked first time. I took this code from https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates , I don't know why they do it like this if it causes problems.

Comment: Well, the code from the linked example works fine if you don't do anything long-running in the callback. Your problem is that you are performing a long-running operation in the callback, which is a very bad thing.

Comment: Now the callback after a while stops getting called at all, what can be the reason? The service keeps running.

Comment: If your app goes to the background, there are a lot of limitations on background apps getting location. In general, on recent versions of Android, you need special permissions to get location updates while your app in the background.

Comment: Do you see anything in the logcat? Don't filter the logcat or you might miss something important.

Comment: For now I removed the synchronized block and the sleep(1000) for each iteration of the loop and trying to see if it helps. Is it possible to run the entire service on its own thread instead of just the callback? maybe the thread I created is destroyed automatically for some reasons?

Comment: I also lowered the location updates interval to 100 ms instead of 1000

Comment: Some parts of the `Service` must run on the main (UI) thread. The rest should run in background threads. What else is your service doing?

Comment: It listens to location updates , and updates the music volume according to the current speed and the user's settings that are set in the activity. and broadcast the speed and volume back to the main activity to be displayed, and also it has a notification so it can keep running in the background. Also I broadcast the settings values from the activity to the service.